# RabbitMQ & php-amqplib: cunsumer reconnect

Tags: php, rabbitmq

I have a consumer worker in PHP script.

But sometimes the RabbitMQ server stops from running,

I get this error:

```
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught exception 'ErrorException' with message 'fwrite(): send of 19 bytes failed with errno=32 Broken pipe' in /home/user/pusher/rabbitmq-worker/vendor/php-amqplib/php-amqplib/PhpAmqpLib/Wire/IO/StreamIO.php:281
```

I would like to be able to handle this error with a try/catch block to throw a nice error to my console or try to reconnect after a while.

This is what I have code so far:

```
    while (true) {
try {
    $connection = new AMQPStreamConnection(RABBITMQ_HOST, RABBITMQ_PORT, RABBITMQ_USER, RABBITMQ_PASS);
    $channel = $connection->channel();
    $channel->queue_declare(RABBITMQ_DT_QUEUE, false, true, false, false);
    $channel->basic_qos(null, 11, null);
    echo ' [*] Waiting for messages. To exit press CTRL+C', "\n";

    $callback = function($req) {
     sleep(3);//Some task that takes 3 sec
     };
    $channel->basic_consume(RABBITMQ_QUEUE, '', false, false, false, false, $callback);
   while (count($channel->callbacks)) {
   $channel->wait();
    }
   $channel->close();
    $connection->close();
 } catch (Exception $e) {
sleep(1);
}
```

What's missing?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Define next parameter on connection

```
keepalive: true
heartbeat: 15 // An example
```

It is two latest arguments of `AMQPStreamConnection::__constructor()`

NOTE:
if you connect to some distant server, I recommend set high up timeouts

```
connection_timeout: 10
read_write_timeout: 30
```

UPD:
You can catch `ErrorException` and try connect to server again

Comment: error still remains if for any reason (even manually) MQ server will stop/restart,  and will not reconnect

Comment: when socket closed by server or tcp connection broken, your program will down with error anyway

Comment: NOTE! Timeout value rule: timeout >= heartbeat*2+2 http://www.rabbitmq.com/heartbeats.html#heartbeats-timeout

Comment: @Jekis, right. Minimal timeout is `heartbeat * 2`. But why `+2`?